# Passing TimeSpan in Html.EditorFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting a very strange exception.
I have a model with a TimeSpan property and try to create a view.

```
public class Clock {

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public TimeSpan Time {get;set;}
}

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time)
```

That is what I get

```
[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.TimeSpan', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.]
System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +321071
System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +377
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +48
```

I've used this technique in another project and it works, but in my current project it fails and I don't know my. Maybe I've missed something or something is disabled.

Comment: What does your Editor Template look like?

Comment: In my previous project I had only DateTime.cshtml template and it works. So I haven't created Editor Template for TimeSpan.

Comment: That's your problem then. It's probably using a default template, as Editor Templates, by default, use any custom templates you've set up based on name, unless you override by specifying the template name. So you should create a TimeSpan editor template to handle properties of this type.

Comment: Then I don't understand why it works in another project.

Comment: Without seeing the code from that project, it would be hard for us to know either. But I'm speculating either it wasn't a TimeSpan type, or you had an editor template for TimeSpan defined, or you didn't use an editor template. Do you have other editor templates in your current project?

Comment: Also, what happens when you drop the `DateType` and/or `DisplayFormat` attributes?

Comment: Dropping these attributes changes nothing.

Comment: Yes, I have many Editor Templates even Object.cshtml, but I've added breakpoints in all these tempaltes and they have not been caught.

Comment: A breakpoint wouldn't be hit, because it's not making it into the editor template -- the exception occurs when it's trying to bind the property on your model to the model of the template. Try removing the Object.cshtml template, to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thank you, Jerad! I guess I have no choice - will use TimeSpan.cshtml. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem on the current project I'm working on. Things is that my colleagues are not getting the exception.

Comment: @Jerad your solution worked for me. If you create an official Answer, we can vote it up, and make the solution more evident to readers.

Comment: @gavi done, see below.

Answer (score 1):

When using `@Html.EditorFor()`, MVC first looks to see if it can find a template using the default convention (or one you may have defined in a custom `ViewEngine`).

If it can't find one -- and in your case, you didn't have one defined -- then it uses built in templates. In the case of `TimeSpan`, it was trying to use a template for a `String` type, which resulted in the exception you saw.

You will need to explicitly define a `TimeSpan.cshtml` template, typed with `@model TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not so much an answer as a workaround, since I'm not sure of the reason for the exception, but for me it works if I do a clean checkout from TFS.